# How do I use GMM or LDV to handle a big problem with autocorrelation in a data frame spanning 1945-2018?

Tags: r, autocorrelation, fixed-effects-model, generalized-moments

For an exam (results for this exam do not need to be entirely accurate and explain the all variations in our variable) I am doing an analysis of (all countries in the world) of whether parliaments with a higher percentage composition of women, tend to engage in less wars as aggressor. The data model I've created spans (a bit unrealistic for an analysis - I've had to recognize) 1945-2018.

Not to my surprise I have now run into the problem of autocorrelation, after conducting a two-way fixed effects model. After reading through some material on how to deal with autocorrelation two methods are suggested as solutions as far as I can see;

Lagged dependent variable (LDV) and GMM (Generalized Method of Moments).
It has come to my attention that GMM might be a bit out of my reach in terms of complexity.

However, which method do you suggest me using? And if so / what tips can you give me for writing the codes for these two methods.

EDIT: I have now tried the following code to lag my dependent variable. However this still returns a significant p-value in the Breusch-Godfrey/Wooldridge test for serial correlation:

```r
# Create lagged dependent variable
finaldatamerged$Dependent_Variable_Lag1 <- lag(
                           finaldatamerged$`Wars started`, 1)

# Estimate a fixed effects model with the lagged dependent variable
laggedfemodel <- plm(finaldatamerged$Dependent_Variable_Lag1 ~ 
    Percent_women_in_parliament + 
    finaldatamerged$`Rate of liberal democracy`, 
    data = finaldatamerged, model = "within", effect = "twoways")

pbgtest(laggedfemodel)
```